# Is it possible to have my Angular frontend subscribed to my Redis Server in Django backend?

Tags: javascript, django, angular, redis

Right now I have to repeatedly call the API to check for Updates.
Is it possible to have a Subscriber kind of method to invoke the API call if changes are made?

Angular.js frontend and django backend server.

Comment: can you please share code what you have done till now?

Comment: You want to connect to Redis server directly from Angular? That's not a good idea. Your Redis server will be open for everyone to connect and that's a huge security risk. Even the official documentation doesn't advise doing this: https://redis.io/topics/security

Comment: For real-time updates, you should consider using an async, even-driven backend, like Tornado. If you want to stick with Django, see [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: the entire project is a taxi service. When I was assigned o it, it was every single API being called by second to check for updation. will check django-channels. thanks for the updates. nop cant share the full code.